# I can not seem to select a dynamicaly generated tr by id[array]

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic

I have a set of  elements that are generated by ajax call to a php script.

```
<tr id="rem[313]">...</tr>
<tr id="rem[345]">...</tr>
```

one of my functions needs to remove a certain tr by id.

I have tried everything but cant seem to select the darn thing

```
function remove_it(x){
$('#rem['+x+']').remove();
$(this).closest('tr').remove; // this i fire from the button click
}
```

to test the select i am using .length and it all returns zero

```
function remove_it(x){
alert($('#rem['+x+']').live().length;
alert($('#rem['+x+']').length);
alert($('#rem['+x+']').on().length);
}
```

Comment: I second David. Especially since you're using double quotes. OR use single quotes.

Comment: You might want to consider adding that id into a `data-*` attribute. This would eliminate the need to escape the contents of your selectors... You could just search for `$("tr[data-foo='"+ x +"']")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select this element:

```
<tr id="rem[313]">...</tr>
```

Use:

```
$('#rem\\[' + x + '\\]')
```

[Simple JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9ATd3/2).

Alternatively, you could simply use:

```
$('tr[id^="rem"][id*="' + x + '"]');
```

[Simple JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9ATd3/1/).

Comment: i have to pass the array index as a variable in the function - x so would i $('rem\\['+x+'\\]')?

Comment: great, escaping worked!! Thank you!! Why do i need to escape the bracket? gotta wait 7 minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: Because they're used in jQuery selectors, and CSS, for attribut-equals, attribute-contains and attribute-exists notation.